# Cómo extraer una parte de una cadena de texto con SUBSTRING y CHARINDEX?

Tags: sql-server

Hola espero me puedan ayudar con esta consulta, tengo que extraer la última parte del link de una imagen, hice la extracción del link completo haciendo uso de SUBSTRING Y CHARINDEX, quedo de la siguiente manera:

```
DECLARE @Cadena VARCHAR(MAX)='<meta property="og:image" content="https://perfumeriaspigmento.com.ar/media/catalog/product/cache/image/300x328/beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582/9/9/999947.jpg">'

SELECT @Cadena = SUBSTRING(@Cadena,CHARINDEX('t="',@Cadena) + LEN('t="'),LEN(@Cadena))
SELECT @Cadena = SUBSTRING(@Cadena,1,CHARINDEX('"',@Cadena) - 1)
SELECT @Cadena
```

RESULTADO:

```
https://perfumeriaspigmento.com.ar/media/catalog/product/cache/image/300x328/beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582/9/9/999947.jpg
```

Pero lo que necesito es solo la última parte "999947" sin el ".jpg" de ser posible, ¿Cómo podría hacer ese filtro?

De antemano, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar Reverse, para forzar el encuentro del último /

```
DECLARE @Cadena VARCHAR(MAX)='https://perfumeriaspigmento.com.ar/media/catalog/product/cache/image/300x328/beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582/9/9/999947.jpg'

SELECT reverse(substring(reverse(@cadena),5,(charindex('/',reverse(@cadena)))-5))
```

Salida:
999947